# Message Box that requires you to type in yes or no

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to have a message box that requires you too type in yes or no to activate the code.

For example you click a button and it says Please type in yes to blablablabl or no to cancel.

Do I need to create an extra form to do this??

This is how I am currently doing it with dialog box:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to change your DNS to Point to Ohio?", "Ohio DNS Change", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

                    }
                    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to make your own form.

Comment: See [Pure C# InputBox](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/361925/pure-c-inputbox)  or maybe [this one, which is less code and better explained.](http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2003/c-inputbox)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "type" yes or no, then yes you would need an extra form to do so.  Otherwise, the message box that you're using to display the message to allow you to "click" on yes or no should be fine.